# How To close iframe within/from inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a `iframe` from one my websites that I use on some other domains. This `iframe` will slide out from left side of the window and will only take 600px of the width on that page.

I want to let users to be able to close the `iframe`, when they click on **close button**.

This **Close button** is inside the same *url/src* of the iframe.

I was wondering how can I make it so when user clicks on **Close button** it adds `display: none` to the *`iframe`/parent `iframe`*

*This is the `iframe` used on other sites:*

```
<iframe src="http://iframe-src.com/this/iframe" id="iframe">
```

*This is what I have in `http://iframe-src.com/this/iframe` source code:*

```
function CloseIframe() {
  document.getElementById('iframe').style.display = "none";
}

<p onclick="CloseIframe()">Close</p>
```

Comment: code please .....

Comment: Why dont you simply add the close button on top of the iframe as part of the main window?

Comment: Please show your code once to see what you have tried

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks for your comment. Because I don't have access to the main window, since some of the sites are not my sites

Comment: "I don't have access to the main window, since some of the sites are not my sites"  Then you won't be able to hide the iframe, or do anything else to the main window, unless those sites specifically permit you access via CORS.  (But how are you doing the "slide out from left side of the window" bit? is that handled inside the iframe or by the parent window?)

Comment: They get the iframe source from me, but I don't want to make them to add more things then the iframe code

Comment: How are you doing the "slide out from left side of the window" bit? is that handled inside the iframe or by the parent window?

Comment: By the parent Window.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be possible without the cooperation of the owners of the parent sites: cross-domain security rules will prevent you from directly reaching into the parent to hide the iframe itself.  The closest you could come would be to hide the contents of the iframe (by setting `display:none` on the body, for example) -- this would make the frame itself invisible, but clicks within the iframe area will not fall through to the parent window. (This unfortunately appears to be the case even if you set `pointer-events:none` on the framed `body`.)

Your best bet is probably to provide these sites with a script they can embed along with your `iframe` tag, which would handle the "opening" and "closing" of the frame from within the parent, avoiding the cross-domain issue altogether.  (For that matter that script could also inject the iframe itself, so they'd still have only one element to add into their document; it'd just be a script tag instead of an iframe.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://iframe-src.com/this/iframe" id="iframe"> </iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function CloseIframe() { 
        document.getElementById('iframe').style.display = "none";  
        } 
</script>
<p onclick="CloseIframe()">Close</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @BCPNAYAK It doesn't work. The problem is is that `CloseIframe` is served from iframe source and it has to first get the parent iframe, which it doesn't now

Comment: Sure. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` `at closeIframe (votes?url=http://www.hallo.com/navid/test/&t=1:250)
    at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick (` `at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick (votes?url=http://www.hallo.com/navid/test/&t=1:71)`

Comment: I have updated once try again please it's working fine. @FriendofAfriend

Comment: Sorry i have understand your problem clearly now, you wish to close the parent iframe of other sites who are seeing your site from their iframe, it is not possible you can change attributes of only your document you can't change others document attributes... but if you wish to close your own documents iframe then use the code what i have updated now @FriendofAfriend